# When Firebug is enabled, click events cause Firefox to lag and eventually crash

Tags: firefox, firebug

I originally thought this is issue with StackOverflow but later I figured cause of my problem is Firebug. This happens on two different computers, both with windows 7.

What happens is that when Firebug is enabled, clicking things often doesn't work (eg. I can't vote on posts on first try) and scrolling with wheel button also doesn't work.

I tried to download the latest version of Firebug `(2.0.16)` but the issue persists. My Firefox version is `45.0.2`.

My question is what can I do to stop that? Disabling the firebug resolves the problem immediately.

Comment: You missed to mention your Firefox and Firebug versions. Also, what did you try so far?

Comment: @SebastianZartner You're aware of any particular version where this happens? When I noticed the problem I ensured that all relevant software is up-to-date - I guess that answers both of your questions.

Comment: I remember the first versions of 2.0 had huge issues related to the *Script* panel, more precisely the debugger module, which were fixed in later bugfix versions. Though I didn't see any issue like this with the latest versions.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't experience this issue myself, this is likely a problem with the *Script* panel, more precisely the debugger module and/or related to memory consumption.

Therefore I suggest you just disable the *Script* panel if you don't need it. If you do need it, then you should follow [Firebug's "first aid" guide](https://getfirebug.com/firstaid).
Among other things this suggests to try if a new Firefox profile fixes the issue.

When your browser crashes, you should normally see the [Mozilla Crash Reporter](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mozillacrashreporter). There you can report your issue to Mozilla, so they can fix the crash. (A browser crash is a Firefox issue, not a Firebug issue.) To see the report later on you can [go to `about:crashes`](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/mozillacrashreporter#w_viewing-crash-reports). From there you can see all your crash reports and also file bugs for them. There are also more [details about troubleshooting Firefox crashes](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-crashes-troubleshoot-prevent-and-get-help) on the Mozilla website.

Another solution to get rid of these issues is to switch to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools).
You'll have to do that anyway at some point, because in upcoming versions of Firefox (I guess the current plan is version 48.0), it will start using [multiple processes for its UI and the websites (aka *Electrolysis* or *E10s* for short)](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Electrolysis) by default, which breaks Firebug 2.0.x.
Then you'll either have to use [Firebug 3.0](https://blog.getfirebug.com/2016/02/08/merging-firebug-into-the-built-in-firefox-developer-tools/), which is basically a theme for the Firefox DevTools possibly offering a few additional features, or just use the DevTools without Firebug.